# High Available SQL Server without SAN by using AlwaysOn feature

Tags: sql-server, storage-area-network, high-availability, failover, sql-server-2012

I have two Microsoft SQL Servers (v 2012) and I want to make them mirror and when one of them goes down the second one will be replaced.

**AlwaysOn** is a new feature in SQL Server 2012 that is designated to High availability solutions. I must say that I don't have SAN.

**Is it possible to create high availability in this scenario? What is the best solution without SAN?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AlwaysOn feature (more appropriately called availability groups as "AlwaysOn" is the generic term for HA that also includes failover clustering) that you mention can be set up in a "share nothing" scenario. Which is to say that you don't need to have a SAN at all since the disks for each server can come from anywhere. You just need two 2012 enterprise edition instances and you can start setting it up.

Comment: I studied about AlwaysOn and it is stated that this feature is available to use in public cloud for a scenario without SAN? Is using public cloud a must?

Comment: Where idid it state that? I did not find that (ridiculous) statement anywhere.

Comment: I sure hope not as I have it configured just this way in my on premises environment.